# How do I figure out a src block's language while filtering an export in Org Mode?

Tags: org-mode

Let's say I have the following code:

```lisp
(defun pygments-org-html-code (code backend info)
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    (message "The src block's language: %s" (org-element-property :language code))
))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-src-block-functions
             'pygments-org-html-code)
```

How do I make it print out the correct language? Is this encoded somewhere in the info parameter? If so, how so I get at it? My attempt at using `org-element-property` doesn't work.

Comment: Seems the first argument doesn't contain an org-element, but "the transcoded data, as a string". See `(describe-variable 'org-export-filter-src-block-functions)`.

Comment: The `info` parameter contains a parse tree of the whole buffer but there is no indication of which particular source code block is being processed, so you cannot correlate the source code block to the parse tree. The only telltale sign is the `code` string which would contain something like `"\\begin{minted}[]{shell}\necho Hello\n\\end{minted}\n\n"` (in my case I used `minted` for the coloring/fontification of source code blocks during LaTeX export). So you could parse the string to get `shell` but it's very specific (e.g. `listings` would use something different in the LaTeX exporter (cont)

Comment: ... and the HTML exporter would be completely different). Why do you need the language at this specific time in the export process? Isn't it a bit late? What are you planning to do with it?